# iPad: new 4/5 finger multitasking gestures - when is the app's screenshot taken?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

When my app resigns activation it covers the current view with a black view to prevent iOS from taking a screenshot of the potentially sensitive document being shown.

When pushing the app to background this works fine. The screenshot is taken AFTER didEnterBackground.
Using multitasking gestures to switch back shows the black view.

However with the new 4/5 finger gestures if you swipe left or right, first "resign activation" is triggered and then "did enter background" but the screenshot seems to be taken BEFORE these events.
How to prevent it in that case?

Comment: You probably shouldn't worry about a feature that isn't directly available to the public. Since the documentation states that you can change the UI in those methods to alter the screenshot, so either that will again be true or they will provide some new method before they make the gestures standard.

Comment: Update: it is going to be fixed in iOS5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to avoid this problem:

http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2011/01/14/whats-in-your-ios-image-cache-backgrounding-snapshot/

And the issue is that the behavior doesn't match what Apple documents here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW21

If that's true, then this definitely sounds like a bug -- but you do realize the gesture you mentioned is apparently a developer feature that's not available to the public (and under NDA)?

I'd do the following:

1. Sumbit a bug report - http://bugreport.apple.com/
2. Ask on the Apple Developer Forums (and include the bug number). People can speak freely there, and it's possible that an Apple developer will respond or at least notice your post (and hopefully prioritize the bug).
3. Finally, if you really want a response from Apple, then problems like this are a perfect use for your technical support incidents. You get 2 of these per year included with your ADC membership: http://developer.apple.com/support/resources/technical-support.html

Comment: AFAIK it is no longer a pure developer thing or under NDA - at least it has shown up on a new device we have at the company that has not been used for development. It seems it appeared with 4.3.2. I'll check the Apple dev forums as you propose. Thanks.

Comment: The description in the documentation dies indeed not match the behavior I see when using the gestures. It works as designed when pushing the app to back using the home button. Meanwhile I have seen other apps suffering from the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

Which "resign activation" ?

Have you tried UIApplication delegates method **didResignActive** or **willResignActive** ?
Or have you set a listener on a specific notification ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of kludgy, but you could code your app to sense when more than 3 or 4 fingers are touching/moving and throw up the "shield screen", then remove the shield n second(s) after the fingers are removed in case the 3or4+ finger touch/move was indeed one of the app-switching gestures.